# Can I use Google Tag manager to track local file activity? (non hosted interactives)

Tags: local, google-tag-manager

We have several interactive kiosks with files that run locally off of the hard drive. They are not "local" hosted, no web server involved. We have internet connectivity. Can we track user interactions with Google Tag Manager? I have read a few posts that seem to indicate it's possible, but the set up has changed dramatically since they were authored. 
We have our GA and GMT setup, with the appropriate scripts embedded within the local html index file. We have set up a container, and several tags and triggers for simple tracking of page views. But there is no live data coming into my GA dashboard. I am sure I am missing steps if this is possible. Any help much appreciated.

---

Hoping I am headed right direction here - but still no tracking - where do I get a clientID to manually pass in? Thank you!!!

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-X',{
  'storage':'none',
  'clientId': 'XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX'
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about GTM, but it is much more likely that your problem is with Google Analytics. There is nothing that prevents GTM from running in a local file (unless you use a very old GTM snippet  - I think before GTM switched completely to https, Google used an url without protocol, that would need to be changed), but Google Analytics will not work in a default installation if it cannot set cookies (which in a local file it can't).

At the very least you would have to set the "storage" field to "none" in your GA tag or GA settings variable, and then pass in a client id manually (in a kiosk it is rather hard to determine when a new visit starts, so maybe you could set a different client id every time users return to a home screen or something like that. Or you just live with the fact that everybody is the same user in GA).